# How to bulk insert into SQLITE database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I am developing UWP application.

I have a database that should be initialized with about 20,000 records. The records, that are defined as follows:

```
private static readonly ObservableCollection<TickRecord> TickRecords = new ObservableCollection<TickRecord>();
```

I tried to insert the records one at a time like this:

```
private void CreateFakeTickRecords()
{
if ( Database.Database.CountTickRecords() > 0 )
    {
    return;
    }

foreach ( var tickRecord in TickRecords )
    {
    Database.Database.AddOrUpdateTickRecord( tickRecord );
    }
}
```

and

```
public static void AddOrUpdateTickRecord( TickRecord tickRecord )
{
    // Create a new connection
    using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) )
    {
    if ( tickRecord.Id == 0 )
        {
        // New
        db.Insert( tickRecord );
        }
    else
        {
        // Update
        db.Update( tickRecord );
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, however it is way too slow.

I would like to modify it so I can do a "Bulk Insert".

How do I do that?

Thx

Comment: Can't you just add the db file with the initial dataset to the app-package and just copy it to the storage on first use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the InsertAll and UpdateAll functions. Hopefully this opens up the database table just once and inserts/updates everything at once. You will need to figure out which objects to insert/update ahead of time, but this should still really speed things up.

```
List<TickRecords> updates = new List<TickRecords>(); 

List<TickRecords> inserts = new List<TickRecords>();  

foreach ( var tickRecord in tickRecords ) 
{   
    if ( tickRecord.Id == 0 )
    {       
        updates.Add(tickRecord);
    }
    else
    {       
        inserts.Add(tickRecords);
     } 
}



using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) ) 
{
     db.InsertAll(inserts);
     db.UpdateAll(updates);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should insert all 20K records in single sqllite transaction.

Something like this:

```cs
using System.Data.SQLite;
...

public static void AddOrUpdateTickRecords(ObservableCollection<TickRecord> tickRecords)
{
    // Create a new connection
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath))
    {
        //open transaction for rollback
        db.BeginTransaction();
        
        try
        {
            foreach (var tickRecord in tickRecords)
            {
                if (tickRecord.Id == 0)
                {
                    // New
                    db.Insert(tickRecord);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Update
                    db.Update(tickRecord);
                }
            }
            
            //send the data
            db.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //do rollback, if has some problem to insert
            db.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. db.BeginTransaction returns void in UWP implementation of SQLITE.

Answer (score 1):

I modified Bibek answer a bit to match it to UWP:

```
        public static void AddOrUpdateTickRecords( ObservableCollection<TickRecord> tickRecords )
        {
        // Create a new connection
        using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) )
            {
            db.BeginTransaction();
            try
                {
                foreach ( var tickRecord in tickRecords )
                    {
                    if ( tickRecord.Id == 0 )
                        {
                        // New
                        db.Insert( tickRecord );
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        // Update
                        db.Update( tickRecord );
                        }
                    }

                db.Commit();
                }
            catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                db.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
```