# Insert a list<collection> to sql lite database UWP

Tags: sql, list

I have a list  of user  retrieved from the code below:

```
var Response1 =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonstring);

Public class User
{
public string userid {get; set;}
public string username{get; set;}
public  string pwd {get; set;}
}
```

is there any way insert the Response1 (`type of List<User>`) to the existing  sqlite user  table  (uwp) other than for each method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778304/how-to-bulk-insert-into-sqlite-database here's an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SQLiteConnection.InsertAll Method](http://www.rbdocumentation.com/html/c2557fc4-855c-bafc-99cb-b582d70298e8.htm) :

```
using ( var db = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath ) ) 
{
     db.InsertAll(Response1);
}
```

I hope to be helpful:)